# asymptotic complexity of post traversal + deletion

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I wanna ask what the time complexity of post traversal in BST if I removed some specific nodes in it while doing the traversal, for example: A dictionary BST that has a word, and a meaning. We want to delete all words with data equal to an empty string, the tree could be unbalanced.

this is my algorithim:

```
void delete_nodes(Node*& node) {
if (node == nullptr) {
return;
}

delete_nodes(node->left);
delete_nodes(node->right);

if (node->data == "") {
// Node to be deleted has 0 or 1 child
if (node->left == nullptr) {
  Node* temp = node->right;
  delete node;
  node = temp;
} else if (node->right == nullptr) {
  Node* temp = node->left;
  delete node;
  node = temp;
} else {
  // Node to be deleted has 2 children
  // Swap the values of the node and the leftmost node in its right subtree
  Node* temp = node->right;
  while (temp->left != nullptr) {
    temp = temp->left;
  }
  node->data = temp->data;

  // Set the data of the leftmost node in the right subtree to an empty string
  temp->data = "";

  // Delete the leftmost node in the right subtree
  delete_nodes(node->right);
}
 }
}
```